# Brouwer fixed point theorem

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, time-travel, arrow-of-time, closed-timelike-curve

How does the [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem) (which provides a solution to the photo camera paradox of a causal loop) generalise to show that objects in closed time-like curves do not violate the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: You mean this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01502.pdf ?